# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'string' while importing flask

Tags: python, flask

I have my project working on my pc. I am trying to transfer it on different PC.
I have every package installed in virtualenvironment like flask, flask-security etc and it works great on my pc.

But when I transfer it to other pc it fails. It cannot even import the Flask and fails with .

```
(env) E:\quickAuto>env\Scripts\python.exe
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bi
```

t (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    from flask import Flask

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 1, in 
>         File "E:\quickAuto\env\lib\site-packages\flask__init__.py", line 17, in 
>        
>         from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
>         File "E:\quickAuto\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug__init__.py", line 151, 
>         in 
>          **import**('werkzeug.exceptions')
>         File "E:\quickAuto\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 67,
>         in
>          from werkzeug._internal import _get_environ
>          File "E:\quickAuto\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug_internal.py", line 12, 
>          in 
>          import string
>          ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'string'

Comment: you copy your package with `virtualenv` folder ?

Comment: yes all the packages are in the env\Lib\Site-packages folder

Comment: I think it is somehow related to sys.path because  i can see that sys.path contains references from the pc that I copied from.. Look at the c:\\users\piyujain... this path is coming from my original PC.. How can i fix this? `>>> print (sys.path)
['', 'E:\\quickAuto\\env\\Scripts\\python36.zip', 'E:\\quickAuto\\env\\DLLs', 'E
:\\quickAuto\\env\\lib', 'E:\\quickAuto\\env\\Scripts', 'c:\\users\\piyujain\\ap
pdata\\local\\continuum\\anaconda3\\Lib', 'c:\\users\\piyujain\\appdata\\local\\
continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs' , 'E:\\quickAuto\\env', 'E:\\quickAuto\\env\\lib\\sit
e-packages']
>>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy all project with the `virtualenv` folder this is a bad practice, you need only to copy the project with the `requirements.txt` file, and install all packages from `requirements.txt` for example:

```
# activate your virtualenv on your PC
. env/bin/activate

# now we need to create a requirements.txt file with `pip freeze`
pip freeze > requirements.txt

# now in our folder we have a `requirements.txt` file with all our packages

# after this copy all your packge without `virtualenv` folder,
# but with `requirements.txt file


# when you are on another PC create a new `virtualenv` activate it and install 
# the packages from `requirements.txt` with this command

pip install -r requirements.txt
```

[some docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove env folder and files because has configurations of your another computer, so create a new one env and just execute pip freeze -r requeriments.txt to install depenedencies